# TF tflite toco: Unsupported operator: Pad

Tags: tensorflow-lite

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco     --input_file=resnet_v2_152/model.pb     --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE     --output_file=resnet_v2_152/model.tflite     --inference_type=FLOAT  --input_type=FLOAT --input_arrays=input     --output_arrays=resnet_v2_152/predictions/Reshape_1   --input_shapes=1,224,224,3
======================================================
2017-12-07 21:53:10.782352: W tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco_cmdline_flags.cc:177] --input_type is deprecated. Use --inference_input_type.  
2017-12-07 21:53:11.357279: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 2003 operators, 2977 arrays (0 quantized)  
2017-12-07 21:53:11.745847: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After general graph transformations pass 1: 319 operators, 739 arrays (0 quantized)  
2017-12-07 21:53:11.749607: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before dequantization graph transformations: 319 operators, 739 arrays (0 quantized)  
2017-12-07 21:53:11.751028: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/allocate_transient_arrays.cc:312] Total transient array allocated size: 11239424 bytes, theoretical optimal value: 9633792 bytes.  
2017-12-07 21:53:11.752708: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco_tooling.cc:264] Estimated count of arithmetic ops: 21.8689 billion (note that a multiply-add is counted as 2 ops).  
2017-12-07 21:53:11.753937: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tflite/export.cc:192] Unsupported operator: Pad  
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pad` is not supported by TensorFlow Lite yet. The team is working on supporting more ops (including `Pad`) now. Hopefully it will work in the near future.

Please refer to [this doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/tf_ops_compatibility.md#unsupported-operations) to see the current ops compatibility.